# How can we restrict user to click a button only one time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to restrict user to click the button only one time.

I have something like this in asp.net
Can we used something like control validator or something?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Height="22px" Text="Enter" Width="100px" />
```

Comment: 'Disable' the button after it has been clicked.

Comment: Yes i am doing that.i just want know if we can do different ways.

Comment: What other way would you want it - why? (You can use data-bound values in the ASP.NET markup.)

Comment: I know why you're trying to do that, but the idiomatic practice in HTTP is to ensure that you can in fact repeat most actions with no problems (look up "idempotency").

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to not click twice in a row, use javascript:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="this.disabled=true" />
```

If you want the button to be ever clicked once, the easy way is to set a cookie or session variable or something, and disable the button from code-behind.